# ruby: undefined method exclude?

Tags: ruby

I try to use the opposite method of include? in ruby, which is "string|array.exclude?", here's my code on interactive ruby.

```
this = "nice"
puts this.exclude? "n"
```

However, it always declares an error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
>     4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `<main>'
>     3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `load'
>     2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
>     1: from (irb):14
> ```
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `exclude?' for "nice":String)

I researched a lot but didn't find a solution. I wonder if it only happens to me, it annoys me so much.

Could someone help me out. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: !"string".include?(pattern) doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String#exclude?` is a part of activesupport gem that gets installed with every rails project. It is not included into ruby's standard library. But this method is [quite simple](https://apidock.com/rails/String/exclude%3F):

```rb
def exclude?(string)
  !include?(string)
end
```

Comment: Alternatively you can load activesupport directly into your ruby project. Depending on your needs it might be recommendable to only load the core-extensions that you really need as described on this guide: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html

Comment: You need 2 patterns, a string to match and a pattern, should be something like !string.include?(pattern) or !string[/regexp/], or... you need to inject that method into String class and I would not do that...

Answer (score 2):

Give a try with this

```
unless this.include?
```